# Form Filter issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having an issue that should be simple to fix but I keep having issues. I'm attempting to setup a filter that brings up the previous week and the current week using `datepart` functions. But I keep getting either a type mismatch error or it won't filter at all but no error. I'm sure it's just the way i'm trying to connect the two `datepart` functions. I've tried to use `between` but that doesn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
Private Sub Filter_2_Week_Click()

'Filter Tasks by last 2 weeks
Me.Tasks.Form.Filter = "(DatePart('ww', [DueDate]) = DatePart('ww', Date()))" And "(DatePart('ww', [DueDate]) = DatePart('ww', Date())-1)"
Me.Tasks.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting the 2 parts with `And`. But since a given week is either the current week *or* the previous one, you must connect the 2 tests with `Or`.

```
Me.Tasks.Form.Filter = "DatePart('ww', DueDate) = DatePart('ww', Date()) Or DatePart('ww', DueDate) = DatePart('ww', Date())-1"
```

Also, everything must be inside the same string. You are connection two strings with `And`. `And` is not a string operator but a logical operator and it must be part of your condition which is contained in the string.

I'm not sure if testing the week is sufficient. You might have to test the year also. Another question is, what happens when the current week is week 1? After subtracting 1 you get 0, but there is no week number 0. The previous week would be week 52 or 53 of the previous year. You better get the current day and subtract 7 days, then test year and week: `DateAdd('d', -7, Date())`

```
Me.Tasks.Form.Filter = "Year(DueDate) = Year(Date()) And " _
  & "DatePart('ww', DueDate) = DatePart('ww', Date()) Or " _
  & "Year(DueDate) = Year(DateAdd('d', -7, Date())) And " _
  & "DatePart('ww', DueDate) = DatePart('ww', DateAdd('d', -7, Date()))"
```

Note the `And` has a higher precedence over `Or`, like `*` is executed before `+` in arithmetic.

Boolean operators:

```
+-------+-------+---------+--------+
| A     | B     | A And B | A Or B |
+----------------------------------+
| False | False | False   | False  |
| False | True  | False   | True   |
| True  | False | False   | True   |
| True  | True  | True    | True   |
+-------+-------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple. I didn't think of using OR because I thought it would want to do one or the other in the filter not both.

Comment: It always tests both, but with `And`, condition 1 AND condition 2 must be `True`. With `Or` condition 1 OR condition 2 must be `True`.

Comment: Does this work with only two conditions? I'm attempting to add one more filter to this function but not having luck. Trying to add `or [status]<>'100' `at the end but doesn't want to filter. I've also tried `and` what's strange is if you go into the filter manually 100 is filtered out but it's not actually filtering.

Comment: Is [status] a number of a text column? If it's a number test `[status]<>100`. Also you might want to test (pseudo code) `(DueDate=this week OR DueDate=previous week) AND status<>100`. But it depends what you want the result to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the better understanding of `and` & `or` I'm self taught so always something new to learn!

Answer (score 0):

*Filter* must be one string, something like:

```
Me!Tasks.Filter = "DateDiff('ww', [DueDate], Date()) Between 0 And 1"
```

Comment: I did try this but it comes up with a property  does not recognize the object or method error.